# form script pass strength and generate pass

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have following script for my password input on a form :

```
$('#genPass').click(function() {
    var password = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    password += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    $('input[name="password"]').val(password);
    document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = password;


});

function passwordStrength(password)

{

    var desc = new Array();

    desc[0] = "Very Weak";

    desc[1] = "Weak";

    desc[2] = "Better";

    desc[3] = "Medium";

    desc[4] = "Strong";

    desc[5] = "Strongest";



    var score   = 0;



    //if password bigger than 6 give 1 point

    if (password.length > 6) score++;



    //if password has both lower and uppercase characters give 1 point      

    if ( ( password.match(/[a-z]/) ) && ( password.match(/[A-Z]/) ) ) score++;



    //if password has at least one number give 1 point

    if (password.match(/\d+/)) score++;



    //if password has at least one special caracther give 1 point

    if ( password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/) ) score++;



    //if password bigger than 12 give another 1 point

    if (password.length > 12) score++;



     document.getElementById("passwordStrength").innerHTML = desc[score];

     document.getElementById("passwordStrength").className = "strength" + score;


}
```

Input field and generate password button :

```
<input name="password" type="password" size="25" maxlength="20" id="pass" onchange="passwordStrength(this.value)" onselect="passwordStrength(this.value)" onclick="passwordStrength(this.value)"/>


<button id="genPass" type="button">Generate Password !</button>
```

now once you click on a button it generates a password into the password input, but only once you click in the password input field , the pass strength  will show.
I want it to show strength as you click on the generate button , any ideas?

Comment: How come your special chars regex is missing so many special chars?

Comment: generating password in JS? This isn't a good practice, will be better that you use `ajax` to get password from `PHP` script. Hide logic and use better tools.

Comment: @mkjasinski , asked for help...not to be judged but thanks :/

Comment: @Lefty ok, sorry, for me help isn't only for debug code, but also how to use a hint of good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#genPass').click(function() {
    var password = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    password += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    $('input[name="password"]').val(password);
    document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = password;
    passwordStrength(password); //added this

});
```